# KnockoutJS - Bind an object to a table depending on a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to map an object to a table using Knockout. To begin, I'll show you my object:

```
function tableViewModel() {
    var self = this;     
    self.data = ko.observableArray();  

self.data.push(
    {
        "Warnings": {
            "numbers": 30,
            "content": [
              {
                "number" : 3001,
                "description" : "There may be a problem with the device you are using if you use the default profile"
              },
                {
                "number" : 3002,
                "description" : "There may be a problem with the device you are using if you don't use the default profile"
              }
            ]
        },
        "Errors": {
            "numbers": 20,
            "content": [
              {
                "number": 1000,
                "description": "No network is loaded"
              },
                {
                "number": 1000,
                "description": "No network is loaded"
              }
            ]
        }
    }
);

    self.dataTitle = ko.observable("Warnings")             
}

ko.applyBindings(tableViewModel());
```

This object contains two "objects", Warnings and Errors. I want to be able,in knockout, depending on a variable (in that case on the variable dataTitle), to show only the content of Warnings (if dataTitle == "Warnings") or the content of Errors.

Basically, I want it to look for the object corresponding to the content of dataTitle.

I'm trying to achieve something like this but oviously it isn't working:

```
<table class="table table-hover" data-bind="foreach: data">
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <th style="width:100px">Numero</th>
           <th>Description</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: data[dataTitle].content"> <!-- This line is not giving expected results -->
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.number"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.description"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's a JSFiddle representing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/bqcMR/

**My question is: is there a way to do that using KnockoutJS or that's to much to ask for ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can put the table into a template, if you only want to have it in your page once, but this works:

```
<tbody data-bind="visible: $root.dataTitle() === 'Warnings', foreach: $data.Warnings.content">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: number"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody data-bind="visible: $root.dataTitle() === 'Errors', foreach: $data.Errors.content">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: number"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

You've basically got one table for each section, and only show the one that you want.

I made some other changes to the view model whilst trying to get this to work, I'm not sure if they are needed though. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqcMR/5/).

Comment: Hopefully, I would like to not being able to split my data. If that's not possible then I'll have to cope with it.

Comment: That's something interesting. It would have been nice to be able to not replicate code but that's not a big deal !